# How to cycle through each div's display property to "display:none" to "display:block" in an endless loop with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div that shows gif image and I have 4 gif image to cycle through with different duration in an endless loop(gif should cycle through 1 2 3 4 then 1 2 3 4 endlessly)

My gifplayer div: Other than the first div the other 4 divs initial display property is set to none

```
<div id="gifplayer"><img id="gif1" class="gifimg" src="gif1.gif">
<div id="gifplayer"><img id="gif2" class="gifimg" src="gif2.gif" style="display:none;>
<div id="gifplayer"><img id="gif3" class="gifimg" src="gif3.gif" style="display:none;>
<div id="gifplayer"><img id="gif4" class="gifimg" src="gif4.gif" style="display:none;>
```

Each gif has a different duration and I would like to play one another in an endless loop. Below is my jQuery and it works but only for the first time and also only the first gif is playing as expected 2nd, 3rd and 4th gifs are abruptly ending:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#gif1").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif2").css("display","block") 
        $("#gif3").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif4").css("display","none") 
    }, 16000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#gif1").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif2").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif3").css("display","block") 
        $("#gif4").css("display","none") 
    }, 18000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#gif1").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif2").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif3").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif4").css("display","block") 
    }, 67800);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#gif1").css("display","block") 
        $("#gif2").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif3").css("display","none") 
        $("#gif4").css("display","none") 
    }, 16000);
})
```

Comment: `id="gifplayer"` you have duplicate IDs. missing quotes and missing closing tags. Please review the HTML basics. Don't use inline `style` attributes. CSS should be in one place only, and that's your style file or tag.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to remove some information from the existing code and add a placeholder so missed quotes and closing tags but in the actual code, it's all in the right format :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the Modulo operator `%` to reset a `i` counter back to `0`
- Use `classList` 's `.remove()` and `.add()` methods
- Use `data-*` attribute to store a desired *ms* duration time and later read it in JS using `Element.dataset`

```js
const gifify = (EL) => {
  const IMGS = EL.querySelectorAll("img");
  const tot = IMGS.length;
  let i = 0;
  (cycle = () => {
    const IMG = IMGS[i];
    const dur = IMG.dataset.duration || 100; // ms (Fallback to 100ms)
    IMGS.forEach(EL => EL.classList.remove("show")); // Hide all
    IMG.classList.add("show"); // Show one
    i += 1;   // Increment index
    i %= tot; // Loop index
    setTimeout(cycle, dur );
  })();
};

document.querySelectorAll(".gifify").forEach(gifify);
```

```css
.gifify img      { display: none; }
.gifify img.show { display: block; }
```

```html
Infinite cycle trough images with different duration: 
<div class="gifify">
  <img data-duration="300" src="//www.placehold.it/100x100/0bf?text=1">
  <img data-duration="500" src="//www.placehold.it/100x100/fb0?text=2">
  <img data-duration="400" src="//www.placehold.it/100x100/f0b?text=3">
  <img data-duration="100" src="//www.placehold.it/100x100/b0f?text=4">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Roko! Thanks! but the problem with this method is - I can only set a common interval to change the gif images and I have 4 different gifs with 4 different duration Is there a way to wait for the gif to complete and then switch to the next one?

Comment: @Praveen store the desired IMG duration into a `data-duration` attribute and edit the JS accordingly. Edited my answer.